# delete a child object from an object with angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

There's an API which returns data like this

```js
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Past Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-08 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "6",
        "description": "6",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 6,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Bomb Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-10 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "10",
        "description": "10",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 10,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

SERVICES

```
getMenus() {
  this.dataServices.menuList(this.pagedData)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response && response.code === HttpStatus.OK) {
        this.dataList = response.data;
      }
    },

  );
}
```

What i'm currently trying to do is to be able to delete a child object from the data returned from the server, so i have this function

```
deleteItem(item) {
  for (let r = 0; r < this.dataList.meals.length; r++) {
    if (this.dataList.meals[r].id === item.id) {
    this.dataList.meals.splice(r, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

When i call the function i get this error 
 `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Consider using `filter` instead?

Comment: The Json you posted is not valid

Comment: Based on the JSON provided, it seems like your `dataList` is itself an array, so you would need to loop through each item in that to get to the `meals` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through all of your 'menu' items and then filter the 'meals' items as in the code below.

```js
const dataList = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Past Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-08 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "6",
        "description": "6",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 6,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Bomb Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-10 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "10",
        "description": "10",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 10,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function deleteItem(item) {
  return dataList.map(menuItem => {
    const newItem = {...menuItem};
    newItem.meals = newItem.meals.filter(meal => meal.id !== item.id);
    return newItem;
  });
}

const newList = deleteItem({id:30});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newList,0,2));
```

```
return dataList.map(
```

Walks through the outer list of `menu` items and allows a modified value to be returned.

```
newItem.meals = newItem.meals.filter(meal => meal.id !== item.id);
```

Goes through all of the `meals` items and returns false if your selected ID matched the meal id, in this case `30`. If the value returned is true then the `meals` item is included in the filter. Otherwise it is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over this.dataList:

```
deleteItem(item){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataList.length; i++) {
        for (let r = 0; r < element.meals.length; r++) {
            if (this.dataList[i].element.meals[r].id === item.id) {
                this.dataList[i].element.meals.splice(r, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```